# SSH remote execute command with special chars

Tags: ssh, bash

Im trying to run this from my shell:

I have a bunch of machines, so i have this in my .bash_profile

```
function sssh() {
  ssh -i ~/.ssh/supersecret.pem $@
}
```

This is the command:

```
export BOX=mybox.a.domain.com
sssh www-data@$BOX "tail -n 1 /path/to/logs/some.log | awk -F '\t' '{print $1}'"
```

The log file is separated by tabs. Hence the `-F '\t'` on the awk -- which is exactly the issue. Its being escaped and not showing me the column i want. When i run `tail -n 1 /path/to/logs/some.log | awk -F '\t' '{print $1}'` locally on the box it works as expected. How can i fix this?

Comment: @tudor yeah i found the issue, I created an answer for it already. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after some trial and error:

```
ssh www-data@$BOX "tail -n 1 /server/musicgraph/prod/logs/dao.log | awk -F\$'\\t' '{print \$1}'"
```

Comment: If you're not waiting for another answer, you should accept your own answer! :)

Comment: If you don't *need* double quotes, using single quotes around the command will simplify things a great deal.  Though you'll still need to escape some things from the remote shell.